# Confusion about `start` command in Windows `cmd.exe`

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

There are bajillion places where `start` command is mentioned
used like

> `start` *command arguments...*

and I am almost sure it worked for me, but now when I try it it wants to be called like

> `start` *title command arguments...*

and indeed when I run it as

```
start "c:\Program Files (x86)\PSPad editor\PSPad.exe"
```

it opens a terminal window with title "c:\Program Files (x86)\PSPad editor\PSPad.exe" and when I add parameters like

```
start "c:\Program Files (x86)\PSPad editor\PSPad.exe" foobar.txt
```

it complains that "Windows can't find 'foobar.txt'".

Has it changed or are there two versions of it or what is going on?

Comment: Using windows 8 and running 
start /?
shows title should be optional.

Comment: same on Win 7, optional

Comment: Can you specify your OS? I just tested it in windows 7 myself, and although the help does not say it is optional, typing `start cmd` opens a new cmd window as expected. If you receive an error, please tell us the exact error.

Comment: @LPChip: Windows 7.

Comment: @LPChip: `start cmd` is an especially bad example, because if you pass only a title, it starts a new cmd window as well, so it's not immediately obvious whether it took `cmd` to be command or title. I've extended the question with a use-case.

Comment: Maybe it's the quotation marks around the command? I.e. if they're there, it's assumed to be a title?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Indeed, seems to be so.

Answer (score 4):

As I remember, it works this way only. 
So to run a command with space in a command window with title:

```
start "" "command with space" -option
```

If you want a title, you need to specify it in first set of quotes.

The explanation to this behavior is although the `title` is optional argument, but it is also the first argument(if used) to the `start` command, so if you specify a quoted string as first argument, it takes it as `title`.